# Python Falcon routes with simple functions?

Tags: python, falconframework

Taking the following example from the getting started page.

Can I write my route handlers as simple functions?

Without classes, and class instances, member functions, self instance references?

```py
# things.py

# Let's get this party started!
import falcon


# Falcon follows the REST architectural style, meaning (among
# other things) that you think in terms of resources and state
# transitions, which map to HTTP verbs.
class ThingsResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests"""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200  # This is the default status
        resp.body = ('\nTwo things awe me most, the starry sky '
                     'above me and the moral law within me.\n'
                     '\n'
                     '    ~ Immanuel Kant\n\n')

# falcon.API instances are callable WSGI apps
app = falcon.API()

# Resources are represented by long-lived class instances
things = ThingsResource()

# things will handle all requests to the '/things' URL path
app.add_route('/things', things)
```

Comment: Use a [custom router](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.0.1/api/routing.html#routing) - however this requires Falcon 3

Comment: Why? do you not want the object to live in the main app scope? You could do this `app.add_route('/things', ThingsResource())`. But if you don't like their OOP design, why use them over flask?

Comment: @Will, thank you. When is Falcon 3 due for release?

Comment: @Dan, I prefer Flask. I definitely dislike the OOP design, but it's not the worst thing in the world. Coworkers and boss are asking me to use Falcon and I want to try my best to make it to my liking.